# when logging from facebook using django allauth request user is admin

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

i am using python 2.7.6 and django 1.6.5, i have installed django allauth, when i login using facebook. the request.user is admin how can i regeister and display profile of user who is logging through facebook. and this login only works on my computer, i want to make it work on others too

i am using permission_classes in views.py
my setting file

```
SITE_ID = 3

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    .
    .
    .
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    #'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
)

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    #'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        #'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    #),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
        'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',

    )
}

SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.social_auth_user',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.associate_user',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.load_extra_data',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.user.update_user_details'
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'allauth.account.context_processors.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount'
)

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
SITE_ID = 1
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "http://192.168.100.7/userprofile/"
FACEBOOK_APP_ID='my_app_id'
FACEBOOK_API_SECRET='my_app_secret_id'
FACEBOOK_EXTENDED_PERMISSIONS = ['email']
SOCIAL_AUTH_UID_LENGTH = 16
SOCIAL_AUTH_ASSOCIATION_HANDLE_LENGTH = 16
SOCIAL_AUTH_NONCE_SERVER_URL_LENGTH = 16
SOCIAL_AUTH_ASSOCIATION_SERVER_URL_LENGTH = 16
SOCIAL_AUTH_ASSOCIATION_HANDLE_LENGTH = 16

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = \
{
    'facebook':
        {
            'SCOPE': ['email'],
            'AUTH_PARAMS': {'auth_type': 'reauthenticate'},
            'METHOD': 'oauth2',
        },
}
```

and i have added this line un url.py
    " url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')), "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my issue resolved with some changes as follows

i changed my Template Context Processor

```
"django.core.context_processors.debug",
"django.core.context_processors.i18n",
"django.core.context_processors.media",
"django.core.context_processors.static",
"django.core.context_processors.request",
"django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
"django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
"allauth.account.context_processors.account",
"allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount",
```

and removed 'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend', from default authentication classes in rest framework

added

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
   # 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)
```

and uploaded to live server and it worked.